# Is the occurence of a fire accident during the performance of a havan considered a bad omen?

Tags: scripture, worship, yajna, puja, omens

While doing the Gajalaxmi havan a coconut burst open during the pūrṇāhuti and I burnt a few body parts.

Is this a good or bad omen according to Hindu scripture?

Comment: Are you asking whether it's an omen or are you asking whether it's a sin for the fire to get out?

Comment: There is nothing bad in it.

Comment: When the Hawan finished the purnahuti coconut just exploded and the extracted fire fall on my body and I injured. When the hawan finished I got good news, got projects and money. After that I consulted to one learned Brahmani he said its not good. The priest must have done some wrong mantra or he may not spoken Rakshya Mantra before havan. My Havan dress aslo burnt.

Comment: It's bad, very bad. You must have done some mistake in pūrṇāhuti. Pray that you didn't get hurt too much.